# i want to rename my json key get from api call

Tags: angularjs, json, database, key, rename

I have json in this format in my DB.

```
[  
   {  
      ip.src:"192.168.200.10",
      y:1506
   },
   {  
      ip.src:"192.168.200.10",
      y:1506
   },
   {  
      ip.src:"192.168.200.10",
      y:1506
   },
   {  
      ip.src:"192.168.200.10",
      y:1506
   },
   {  
      ip.src:"192.168.200.10",
      y:1506
   }
]
```

I want to change the key name `ip.src` to `name`
for all values using loop

This is my code

```
$http.get("api/data")
     .then(function(data,status){
         if(data){
             $scope.log=data;
             angular.forEach($scope.log, function(value, key){
                 if(key=="data"){
                     $scope.log.data.ip.src=name;
                 }
         }
    }
```

Comment: stringify json , replace string name , at  last parse

Comment: can u explain with sample code

Comment: `JSON.stringify(data)` will turn it into string, where you can change anything manually (try to parse it with `split`, `replace('ip.src', 'name')` or with some _regex_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is what you need here.

```js
const array = [{
    "ip.src": "192.168.200.10",
    y: 1506
  },
  {
    "ip.src": "192.168.200.10",
    y: 1506
  },
  {
    "ip.src": "192.168.200.10",
    y: 1506
  },
  {
    "ip.src": "192.168.200.10",
    y: 1506
  },
  {
    "ip.src": "192.168.200.10",
    y: 1506
  }
];

const changed = array.map(item => {
  item.name = item['ip.src'];
  delete item['ip.src'];
  return item;
});

console.log(changed);
```